# Snowflake Cursor Loop with IF statement

Tags: sql, loops, if-statement, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-cursor

Trying to run the following code and getting an error.

Just want to loop thru two varchar cursors, and do a slightly different action depending on which iteration the loop is on.

There is seemingly something wrong with the curdsor variable in the IF statement, but I cant figure it out.

Any help is appreciated!

```
DECLARE
  VAR_TYPE VARCHAR;
  c4 CURSOR FOR SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM TYPES;

BEGIN
        CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE OBJECT AS (
                SELECT Z.*, D.KEY
                FROM DATA Z
                LEFT JOIN DIMENSION D
                    ON Z.ID = D.ID;

   OPEN c4; 
   
    FOR CLASS_TYPE IN c4 DO
       VAR_TYPE := CLASS_TYPE.DATA_TYPE;

     
        IF (:VAR_TYPE = 'OLD')
        THEN  (DELETE FROM OBJECT WHERE KEY IS NOT NULL) ;
        END IF;

  END FOR;
  CLOSE c4;

  END;
```

Comment: Not sure any of this code make any sense. Can you explain in words what you want to happen.

Comment: @Charlieface Imagine I have a decision tree with two forks, one I want to run on a full set of data, the other fork I want to run on a subset of that data. Call the forks OLD and NEW. The OBJECT table has the full dataset, and OLD records will have the KEY field populated via the left join. I want the loop to run first on the full set, for the NEW iteration of the loop, then as it moves to the OLD portion of the loop, I want it to filter the data, and proceed.

Comment: Please update your question with the error message you are seeing. Can you also provide enough sample data for the source tables so that someone else can try your code - please provide as editable text.

Comment: You're missing an end parenthesis in your create table statement...or don't need the begin parenthesis at all.  Either way, that might be creating weird error messages.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and show that with sample data and expected results, and explain based on that data how the results are produced because I'm really not understanding. I don't get where forks come into it, or why you are looping at all (in SQL you always work on full sets, not loops).